# whats the lifetime of Github OAuth API access token

Tags: github, github-api

what is the expiry time of github oauth access token. And also how do I renew it. I don't see any refresh token in their documentation. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

2014: As commented in this "[GitHub OAuth Busy Developer's Guide](https://gist.github.com/technoweenie/419219#comment-3209)"

> Tokens don't have to expire.
> They only send back the access token and an expiration (field  "`expires_in`", [seen as far back as 2013](https://gist.github.com/technoweenie/419219#gistcomment-825999)) if the `offline_access` scope is not requested (as it is the case for a [refresh token](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/refreshing-user-to-server-access-tokens#renewing-a-user-token-with-a-refresh-token)).
> Right now, GitHub just assumes all apps want offline access.

You can check an [OAuth application authorization](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#check-an-authorization), delete it or revoke it.
But the token itself doesn't seem to be bound to an expiry date **[unless they are not use for one year](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/token-expiration-and-revocation#token-expired-due-to-lack-of-use=)**.

[badsyntax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492325/badsyntax) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902600/whats-the-lifetime-of-github-oauth-api-access-token/26903255?noredirect=1#comment93774284_26903255):

> I also found this useful:
>
> "An OAuth token does not expire until the person who authorized the OAuth App revokes the token."
> From "[Migrating OAuth Apps to GitHub Apps](https://developer.github.com/apps/migrating-oauth-apps-to-github-apps/)".

[Stokito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049542/stokito) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902600/whats-the-lifetime-of-github-oauth-api-access-token/26903255#comment105452423_26903255) to [rfc6749 / 4.2.2 Access Token Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.2):

> ### `expires_in`
>
> RECOMMENDED.
> The lifetime in seconds of the access token.
> For example, the value "3600" denotes that the access token will expire in one hour from the time the response was generated.
> If omitted, the authorization server SHOULD provide the expiration time via other means or document the default value.

Comment: I also found this useful: "An OAuth token does not expire until the person who authorized the OAuth App revokes the token." From https://developer.github.com/apps/migrating-oauth-apps-to-github-apps/

Comment: @badsyntax Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The `expires_in` is described in OAuth spec https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2.2

Comment: Is this still valid? I found it has an ```expires_in``` attribute here: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/refreshing-user-to-server-access-tokens

Comment: @TerryWindwalker Yes, it is. I have edited the answer to explain the general principle.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, the `access_token` of GitHub has no expiry until you revoke the OAuth token.

You can consider to opt in to GitHub App expiration token beta feature. This would make your app use expiring user tokens valid for 8hrs, and refresh tokens valid for 6 months

Here's an official [step by step guide](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/developers/apps/refreshing-user-to-server-access-tokens#:%7E:text=You%20can%20enable%20or%20disable,left%20sidebar%2C%20click%20GitHub%20Apps.)

Comment: This guide is for Github Apps, not OAuth apps.

Answer (score 1):

> GitHub will automatically revoke an OAuth token or personal access token **when the token hasn't been used in one year**.

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/token-expiration-and-revocation#token-expired-due-to-lack-of-use

Interestingly, some other OAuth providers issue short-lived access tokens and long-lived refresh tokens, as suggested discretionally in the [OAuth spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.5). For example, Git*Lab* OAuth ["access tokens expire in two hours"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/oauth_provider.html#expiring-access-tokens) and each refresh token may only be used once. This [mitigates the damage](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/263314/9374) that stolen access tokens can do.