# Do GitHub raw urls expire?

Tags: github

Do GitHub raw urls for private repositories expire?  I'm referring to the link generated when you click the `Raw` button while viewing a file on github.com.

The link includes a token but there's no info about where that token comes from.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No one has clearly mentioned this, but the [github raw urls expire in 7 days](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23845#discussioncomment-3241866).

You can use longer lasting **personal access tokens** generated here: https://github.com/settings/tokens but those can only be used via curl:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token <personal_token>' <raw_url>
```

Note that the **personal access tokens** expire if unused for an entire year.

Comment: As of June 2021 this should be the accepted answer.
Original question and accepted answer are 5 years old at this point and a lot has changed since.

Comment: This method should work for any request-based tool, not just cURL. Just add the header `Authorization: token <personal_token`

Comment: The link is broken for the source. I had the feeling that the links already expire after a few hours, but could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

That token comes from [using OAuth with Git](https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth)

```
https://<oauth-secret>:x-oauth-basic@raw.githubusercontent.com/<me>/<repo>/master/<file>
```

The `raw.githubusercontent.com/<me>/<repo>/master/<file>` part does not expire.
But it is to type '<kbd>y</kbd>' before clicking '<kbd>Raw</kbd>' on the GitHub page, in order to get the SHA1 as part of the url: that way, you are sure to reference always the same file version.

```
https://<oauth-secret>:x-oauth-basic@raw.githubusercontent.com/<me>/<repo>/<sha1>/<file>
                              ^                                             ^^^^
```

The [token part does not "expire"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26903255/6309) (but it can be deleted or revoked)

Comment: It seems like the token at the end of the raw URL does expire.  Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Not sure: you could ask that as a question though.

Comment: Did this question evere been asked? Since github doesn support git archive, we have to do the trouble some way of doing oauth, because raw files expire. I want it easy

Comment: @vonGohren I believe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45931379/6309, but without a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You get a new token whenever the file changes. So edits expire tokens.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at this API document, https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/.

The URL should be:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw' -k \
https://{{githubhost}}/api/v3/repos/{{org}}/{{repo}}/contents/{{path}}?access_token=xxxx
```

It worked for me:

- The access_token is personal access token.
- And the path canbe a file or dir.