# Github Raw File - Can I get a permanent link?

Tags: github

I want to be able to download the latest version of an xml file containing data that exists in my github repository.  However, the token at the end of the file changes when I commit a new version of the file.

Is there a way to prevent the token from changing or somehow find out what it is programmatically?

I need a permanent link I can access...

Answer (score 2):

The token in the URL has nothing to do with the file, it's an authentication token that is needed to download the raw file from a private repo.  It doesn't change when you commit a new file, it changes when your Oauth session expires and you login again.  To get one that doesn't change, just make a Personal Access Token (https://github.com/settings/tokens) and replace the token in the URL with that.

Comment: So this statement is partially true, yes the token is not for the file per-say but when looking at the raw token its an automatically generated auth token.

As far as using a personal auth token as a replacement for the auto generated token on a file in a private repo this does NOT work. ie you cant take url...?token=xxx and replace xxx with your personal token and have it load, this receives a 404.

If you have a way around that or I'm missing something I welcome an update to the above response

Comment: @Rhineb true, the replacement doesn't work, it gives 404

Comment: Apparently using a personal access token there isn't supported any more, but you can still use one either as part of the URL (`https://PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN@raw.githubusercontent.com/...`) or with an auth header (`curl -H 'Authorization: token PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN' 
 -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...`)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use raw.githubusercontent.com and curl that file:

Example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/README.md

That will be default give you the latest of the master branch.
That same URL is listed in [GitHub API repository Content](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents).

Comment: If I do this w/o specifying a token at the end, I get a 404.  I need to specify a token, but this token value changes each time I commit to that file.

Comment: I know about the raw, but the token that comes out expires, so there is a problem to rely on them for the build cases

Comment: @vonGohren I agree. Is there a way to get a new token or refresh that token at each build?