# Is the url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path-to-my-file a permalink in github for public repositories?

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-api

I have a file (pngs) in a public github repository and I would like to give access to this file redirecting people through an url.
Recently I found a raw link to files in github, such as: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user-name/path-to-file.

Is this a permalink? What is the chance of the link to be broken in long term?

Comment: The URL is different for public and private repos. If this is a file from a private repo, see: [Github Raw File - Can I get a permanent link?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45929891/2745495) and [Do GitHub raw urls expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38132908/2745495).

Comment: Ok, but actually these answers refers to private repositories, but what about a public one? My case refers to a public repository.